# Running TestSuite in JUnit4 and Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, junit4, surefire

I am integrating an external `junit.framework.TestSuite` into my library which is built using Maven and JUnit4.  The typical tests, if not all of them, are kicked off using JUnit4 annotations.  How do I incorporate a `junit.framework.TestSuite` into this existing test codebase?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
public class JSR330Tck {
    @Test
    public junit.framework.Test suite(){
        Car car = Factories.get(CarFactory.class).buildCar();
        return Tck.testsFor(car, false, true);
    }
}
```

Or by defining it with a static `suite()` method:

```
public class JSR330Tck {
    public static junit.framework.Test suite(){
        Car car = Factories.get(CarFactory.class).buildCar();
        return Tck.testsFor(car, false, true);
    }
}
```

Both of these are not triggered via the Maven surefire plugin.

Comment: Where are the files located? How does the pom file look like?

Comment: These files are located in the src/test/java directory and the pom.xml looks like the following: https://github.com/johncarl81/transfuse/blob/master/transfuse/pom.xml

Comment: Please see [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html). Your test class name pattern does not match with Surefire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that your test classes are not named based on the naming convention for test in relationship with [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes)

```
includes>
 <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Apart from that you shouldn't use TestSuites, cause surefire-plugin will handle that already. So usually there is no need to suites to be defined separately.

Comment: I wish I could avoid using TestSuites, but I am integrating a 3rd party testing kit.  I'll try to rename my testing class and see if that works.

Comment: Naming the class JSR330TckTest works, as long as I define the method as static and name it suite().  Thanks.

Comment: The test suite feature from junit 3.8 is the only way I know to dynamically generate test cases. Eg, business folk provide input and output in folders, and there needs to be a test run for each of these folders